# Get folder's permissions (short version)

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm using the following code to return detailed folder permissions

[image]

```
return (from permissionName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(FileSystemRights))
            let val =
                Convert.ToInt32(
                    Enum.Parse(typeof(FileSystemRights), permissionName), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            where
                (val != 0x1f01ff) && (val != 0x301bf) && (val != 0x20089) && (val != 0x200a9) && (val != 0x116)
            where ((int)this.FileSystemRule.FileSystemRights & val) > 0
            select permissionName).ToList();
```

How can i get the short version which is:

[image]

In Other words, i want to return only

1. Full Control
2. Modify
3. Read & Execute
4. List Folder Contents
5. Read
6. Write
7. Special (for any other combination)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify your logic quite a bit by just listing those permissions you want. For example:

```
private readonly FileSystemRights[] namesIWant = new FileSystemRights[]
{
    FileSystemRights.FullControl, 
    FileSystemRights.Modify, 
    FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute,
    FileSystemRights.ListDirectory,
    FileSystemRights.Read,
    FileSystemRights.Write
};
```

Then, your LINQ expression becomes:

```
return (from perm in namesIWant
        where (this.FileSystemRule.FileSystemRights & perm) != 0
        select perm.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: You should use `!= 0`instead of `> 0` or cast to `uint`. When somebody extends your code and checks for bit 31 (= GenericRead), then the result is < 0.

Answer (score 1):

I thought to share this with you,
In order to make it work for me, i had to change the `>` singe to `==` 
The code of @Jim Mischel is modified to:

```
return (from perm in namesIWant
        where (this.FileSystemRule.FileSystemRights & perm) == perm 
        select perm.ToString()).ToList();
```

also remove `FileSystemRights.ListDirectory,` from `NamesIWant` because it includes `Read`, and `ReadData`, if you keep it you will have duplicated values.